# ExtJS: How to make a panel full screen based on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, fullscreen

My site has a top bar with dropdown buttons and a bottom bar with other information. In the main body I have a panel with 2 items-> a map and a grid.
On the map I have an afterrender listener which can detect mobile browser. On detecting a mobile browser I want to make the map full screen removing everything else in the window adding a button to go back to regular screen.

```js
items: [{
    xtype: 'gmappanel',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (map, eOpts) {
            var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
            if (isMobile) {
                //make the map full screen
            }

        }
    }
},
    anotherGrid
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap up your gmap panel into a window with maximized config:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    maximized: true,
    title: 'Map',
    frame: false,
    modal: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
}).show();
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gnj

Comment: Thanks, Tyr for your answer but I need to 'fullscreen' the map without opening a new window